# How do you turn on comments for only the last page of a paginated post?

Tags: comments, pagination

I have a single post with page breaks, but I only want to show comments and the ability to comment on the last page. Is this possible with WordPress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to wrap the code that displays the comments in a conditional like this:

```
if ($page === $numpages) {
  echo 'last page'; // this is the last of the <!--nextpage--> pages
}
```

That requires a theme edit, so it is only a good solution if this is a theme you've constructed and maintain.

The variables (`global`) `$page` and `$numpages` are set by [`setup_postdata()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/query.php#L3625) and so should be reliable inside any *properly constructed* Loop.